# Comparing two responses from API but getting Error

Tags: javascript, postman

[This is the error which i am getting. It should check for the element inside userLinesList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrQx9.png)I have two responses :-

```
ResultObj32 (Response1)
"errorDescription": "",
"message": "",
"resultCode": "OK",
"resultObj": {
    "userLinesList": [{
        "lineId": 1,
        "lineType": "MOBILE",
        "lineValue": "11"
    }],
    "externalObject": {

}}
  ResultObj63 (Response2)
{
  "resultCode": "OK",
"errorDescription": "",
"message": "",
"resultObj": {
    "userLinesList": [{
        "lineId": 1,
        "lineType": "MOBILE",
        "lineValue": "11"
    }],
    "externalObject": ""
},
"systemTime": 1536131455

 }
```

I am comparing two response in postman but when i am comparing i am not able to go inside userLinesList and externalObject i am getting it

> as **3.2 value is: [object Object]---6.3 value is: [object Object]**

So i just wanted to get inside this userlist and externalObject to compare

here is the code :-

```
console.log("Entered into assertion check");
tests["3.2 response is"+pm.variables.get("ResultObj32")+ "--------" +"6.3 response is"+pm.variables.get("ResultObj63")] = true;
var x = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("ResultObj32"));
var y = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("ResultObj63"));
console.log("3.2 response object length is "+Object.keys(x).length);
console.log("6.3 response object length is "+Object.keys(y).length);



for (var i=0; i<Object.keys(x).length; i++)
{
    //console.log("Execution entered into first i loop");
    if (y.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(x)[i]) && Object.keys(x)[i] !== "resultObj")
    {
        console.log("Object present:"+Object.keys(x)[i]);
        var key = Object.keys(x)[i];
        console.log("Key is:"+key);
        console.log("Corresponding value in 3.2 is :"+Object.values(x)[i]);
        console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is :"+y[key]);
        tests["Validation of element in response: "+Object.keys(x)[i]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x)[i] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y[key] ]= Object.values(x)[i] === y[key];
    }
    else if (y.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(x)[i]) && Object.keys(x)[i] === "resultObj")
    {

        for (var len=0; len<Object.keys(x.resultObj).length; len++)
        {
            console.log("Element that is getting verified is:"+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]);
            if (y[Object.keys(x)[i]].hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]))
            {
                 console.log("Object present:"+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]);
                 var key = Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len];
                 var y1 = y[Object.keys(x)[i]];
                 console.log("Key is:"+key);
                console.log("Key in 3.2 is:"+key);
                console.log("key in 6.3 is:"+Object.keys(y.resultObj)[len]);
                 console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is:"+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]);

                 if(Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] ==="" && y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]])
                 {
                 tests["Validation of element in resultObj is passed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + "---" + "6.3 value is:   "+Object.values(y.resultObj)[len]]= true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     tests["Validation of element in resultObj is failed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + "---" + "6.3 value is:   "+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]]= false;
                 }
            }
            else if(y[Object.keys(x)[i]].hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]))
            {
                console.log("Object present:"+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]);
                 var key = Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len];
                 var y1 = y[Object.keys(x)[i]];
                 console.log("Key in 3.2 is:"+key);
                 console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is:"+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]);

                 if(Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] === "" && y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]] === "")
                 {
                 tests["Validation of element in resultObj is passed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + "---" + "6.3 value is:   "+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]]=true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                   tests["Validation of element in resultObj is passed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]]=true;   
                 }

            }
            else if(y[Object.keys(x)[i]].hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]))
            {
                console.log("Object present:"+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]);
                 var key = Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len];
                  var y1 = y[Object.keys(x)[i]];
                 console.log("Key is:"+key);
                 console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is"+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]);
                 if(Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] !=="" && y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]] ===null)
                 {
                 tests["Validation of element in resultObj is passed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]]= true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  tests["Validation of element in resultObj is failed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]]= false;   
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                tests["Validation of element in resultObj is failed: "+Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x.resultObj)[len] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y[key] ]= false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Object not present:"+Object.keys(x)[i]);
        tests["Validation of element in response: "+Object.keys(x)[i]+ "----------" + "3.2 value is:  " + Object.values(x)[i] + ":" + "6.3 value is:   "+y[key] ]= false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you created a test? Is that doing the compare. The `object Object` seems like a parse issue. wrapping it in a `JSON.parse()` might help here.

Comment: yes but same issue with this also i am facing :-(

Comment: Can you update the question with the code for the test and how you are checking both responses

Comment: @DannyDainton i am not able to update the question :-(

Comment: Err...can you use the edit button?

Comment: @DannyDainton Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of your Postman window?

Typically, in Postman, when a response is return with nested JSON values there is a drop down arrow next to the object that expands to show contents when clicked.

Comment: unfortunately i am not able to add screenshot :-(

Comment: Can you please have a look i have update the question

Comment: Try putting the objects you're trying to log inside JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 0):

When reviewing your code it seems that you are concatenating a string and a JavaScript object. When this happens you get the "[object Object]". To break out of this "[object Object]" you have three options. You can selectively dereference the object. Try:

```
console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is:"+ y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]].lineId);
```

Or spit out the full object. Try

```
console.log("Corresponding value in 6.3 is:"+ JSON.stringify(y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]));
```

Or put it into a foreach. Try

```
var innerObject = y1[Object.keys(x.resultObj)[len]]);
for(var innerKey in innerObject)
{
    console.log("run your magic code", innerKey, innerObject[innerKey]);
}
```

The challenge with these approaches is that they are going to lead on to high maintenance as time goes on. Consider this approach.

To start with lets add a few elements that are in each object that are not in each other object. Secondly lets change the data type of some object. Take note of lineId. In one it is a string in the other it is a number.

```
var ResultObj32 = {
"errorDescription": "",
"message": "",
"resultCode": "OK",
"internal32":{},
"resultObj": {
    "userLinesList": [{
        "lineId": "1",
        "lineType": "MOBILE",
        "lineValue": "11",
        "notin63": true
    }],
    "externalObject": {

}}};
  var ResultObj63 =
{
  "resultCode": "OK",
"errorDescription": "",
"message": "",
"internal63":{},
"resultObj": {
    "userLinesList": [{
        "lineId": 1,
        "lineType": "MOBILE",
        "lineValue": "11",
        "notin32":true
    }],
    "externalObject": ""
},
"systemTime": 1536131455

 };



function objCompare(obj1, obj2, missing) {
    missing = (undefined == missing ? false : missing);
    Object.entries(obj1).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if(undefined == obj2[key] || null == obj2[key]) {
            console.log(key, "is not in obj2");
            return;
        }
       if (value && ["string", "number", "boolean"].indexOf(typeof value) < 0) {
            objCompare(obj1[key], obj2[key], missing);
            return;
        }
        if(missing){
            return;
        }
        if(obj1[key] == obj2[key] && obj1[key] === obj2[key]) {
            console.log(key, value, "Is in both Objects and they are the same type");
        }
        if(obj1[key] == obj2[key] && obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
            console.log(key, value, "Is in both Objects and they are NOT the same type");
        }
    });
}
```

Lets run the newly changed objects through the above recursive function.

```
console.log("Comparing obj32 to obj63 as obj2");
objCompare(ResultObj32, ResultObj63);
console.log("Comparing ob63 to obj32 as obj2")
var diffOnly = true;
objCompare(ResultObj63, ResultObj32, diffOnly);
```

Notice that I reverse the objects on the second call and the report is always obj2. Then what I get is two result sets one that shows that they are the same and another that shows they are the same but not the same type.

```
Comparing obj32 to obj63 as obj2
errorDescription  Is in both Objects and they are the same type
message  Is in both Objects and they are the same type 
resultCode OK Is in both Objects and they are the same type
internal32 is not in obj2
lineId 1 Is in both Objects and they are NOT the same type
lineType MOBILE Is in both Objects and they are the same type
lineValue 11 Is in both Objects and they are the same type
notin63 is not in obj2

Comparing ob63 to obj32 as obj2
internal63 is not in obj2
notin32 is not in obj2
systemTime is not in obj2
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer but using this its alomost working the way i wanted. Just for the below response its not checking for externalObject ,lineValue and systemtime. And also if in both responses something is not matching then its not displaying in console rather than that it should fail the test                          Response - ResultObj32 (Response1)
"errorDescription": "",
"message": "",
"resultCode": "OK",
"resultObj": {
    "userLinesList": [{
        "lineId": 1,
        "lineType": "MOBILE",
        "lineValue": "11"
    }],
    "externalObject": {

}}

Comment: So, did you need to change the current if statements or add some more if statements to test the failure conditions?

Comment: No I just changed few things in both responses and it was not comparing that